# Site missing from all sites menu on other stackexchange sites

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I found this site last week because it appeared on the all sites menu on one of the other stackexchange sites I was using at the time.  Now it seems it is no longer listed on the all sites menu on any of the other stackexchange sites I use.  What gives?

Comment: Actually it appears to show up on askubuntu, but not linux&unix, skeptics, superuser, and serverfault sites.

Answer (score 2):

It is present in the all sites menu right between Philosophy and Travel, if you sort by oldest.

[image]

Were you looking some where else? It could be possible that you saw an advertisement for the site and these appear randomly and cannot be predicted.

---

In response to your comment below:

Clicking on the all sites tab in the StackExchange menu, I still see this site third from the top.

[image]

I'm not entirely sure, but I believe that the position of a site in the list depends on the rep you have on those sites (>200 rep). For e.g., among the sites I have >200 rep, I have the most rep on SO followed by MSO, then G&L, Math and Cooking and that's the order I see it displayed. After these, it displays the rest of the network sites in presumably random order. I tried this out from multiple SE sites and I'm pretty sure this is the case.

So since you have <200 rep on G&L, what must have happened was that it got shuffled in the list and you just didn't scroll down far enough to see it.

If you access the StackExchange menu from a site where you don't have an account (e.g, programmers.SE for me), the ordering is random. Nevertheless, all the sites are still displayed.

[image]

Comment: There are no sorting options on the all sites link.  You seem to be talking about something else.  I am talking about clicking the StackExchange menu on the top left of all stack exchange sites, and clicking on "all sites" instead of "inbox" or "hot questions".  Gardening shows up on the gardening site, but not on others ( though it did last week ).

Comment: It still appears in the list for me. See my edit above.

Comment: I have scrolled through the entire list multiple times to be sure.  It does indeed appear near the top on the gardening and askubuntu sites, but it is not there on the other sites where I have accounts and am logged in.

Comment: Hrm.. now that I have gone back and forth checking a few more times, it seems to be completely random.  It moves around to different positions and sometimes isn't there at all.  Is this normal?

Comment: It is normal for it to be random, because the idea is to expose people to different sites in the network. However, I don't think they'd drop it from the list (why would they as they need to publicize it!). I think what must've happened is that you accidentally skipped it when scrolling. This has happened to me several times, because all the beta sites have the same sketchbook design and similar logos, it's so easily to mistake GL for GD or something like that.